# For loop from c++ in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a problem with program  in c++ which I rewrite to pyhton... 
I have two diffrent of nested foor loop's

```
for (int i = k + 1; i<size; i++) 
    {
        for (int p = 0; p<k; p++)
        {

        }

    }
```

And

```
for (int k = 0; k<size; k++)  
{
   for (int j = k; j<size; j++)
   { 

   } 
}
```

How can I write foor loop in python to get "i=k+1" or "j=k" in for loop ?

Best regards !

Comment: What would you do in this for-loops? Are you doing some kind of convolution or something?

Comment: It would help if you would provide an example of what you are actually trying to accomplish. Generally nested loops are not the pythonic way of doing things (also most other languages have nicer constructs) and I guess there is a nice solution using itertools or list comprehension for what you are trying to accomplish, but it is not clear from your post what that is.

Comment: I’d suggest you amend your question with more information about the problem you’re trying to solve with these loops. Without any context it’s hard to give a good answer. While you *can* write equivalent loops in Python that’s most likely not an elegant way to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the first for loop:

```
for i in range(k + 1, size):
    for p in range(k):
        pass
```

and here's the second for loop:

```
for k in range(size):
    for j in range(k, size):
        pass
```

Take a look at the range() function in python which goes very nicely with for loops in python.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Comment: I think we should show OP that this is non pythonic. And even not modern c++ instead of blindly answering his question.

Answer (score 0):

The first one looks like you trying to iterate a sequence like that

```
data = [1,2,3,4]
k = 2
out = [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4]]
```

If I'm right that what you need is

```
def nwise_iter(sequence, n):
    iters = itertools.tee(sequence, n)
    for i, iter enumerate(iters):
        for i in range(i):
            iter(iter, None)
    return zip(*iters)

for slice in nwise_iter(data, k):
    pass
```

The second one looks like the desired output should be

```
[[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4], [4]]
```

If this is true then you would want something like that

```
out = [data[i:] for i in range(0, len(data))]
```